# Get machine code of the proccess by PID without attaching a debugger

Tags: linux, debugging, disassembly, machine-code

I want to get a machine code of the running proccess by his PID for analysing malicious instructions, by using heuristic methods of data analysing.

All I need to know is list of current machine instructions and values of registers (EIP, EAX, EBX...).

I can use `gdb` for reach this goal [gdb output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwxrF.png), but is take a several problems:

- I don't know how interact with gdb from my application;
- malicious code can use some technics of debugger detection like this: http://www.ouah.org/linux-anti-debugging.txt 
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTVp4jpJoyc&list=LLw7XNcx80oj63tRYAg7hrsA 
  [for windows](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference);
- Getting info from console output makes work of my application slower.

Is are any way to get this information by PID in Linux? Or maybe Windows?

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look to gcore:

```
$ gcore 
usage:  gcore [-o filename] pid
```

so you can dump process core using its pid:

```
$ gcore 792
warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
0x00007f5f73998410 in ?? ()
Saved corefile core.792
```

and then open it in gdb:

```
$ gdb -c core.792 
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 8.0.1-30.fc26
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[...]
[New LWP 792]
Missing separate debuginfo for the main executable file
Try: dnf --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/09/b9d38bb6291b6282de4a2692e45448828d50da
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
#0  0x00007f5f73998410 in ?? ()
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0xfffffffffffffe00       -512
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x7f5f73998410   140047938061328
rdx            0x1      1
rsi            0x7ffd30683d73   140725415591283
rdi            0x3      3
rbp            0x7ffd30683d90   0x7ffd30683d90
rsp            0x7ffd30683d68   0x7ffd30683d68
r8             0x1d     29
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x3      3
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x4006d0 4196048
r13            0x7ffd30683e70   140725415591536
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x7f5f73998410   0x7f5f73998410
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

or even using the binary image from /proc to get some symbols:

```
gdb -c core.792 /proc/792/exe
```

You may know that you can pass scripts to gdb, this can ease not having to interact with it from your binary (man gdb for more details).

if you don't want to use gdb directly you may try using `ptrace()` directly, but it is for sure more work.

For the anti debugging technics, well... they work and there is no easy way to handle them directly as far as I know, each one may be worked arounded manually, (patching binary, disassembling from unaligned addresses manually by setting then in objdump, etc...)

I'm not an expert of the domain, I hope this will help you a bit.